# A confusion on the definition of *almost everywhere*

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is the definition from Terry Tao's *Introduction to measure theory*:

> A property $P(x)$ of a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is said to hold *(Lebesgue) almost everywhere* in $\mathbb{R}^d$ or *for (Lebesgue) almost every point* $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, if the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for which $P(x)$ fails has Lebesgue measure zero (i.e. $P$ is true outside of a null set).

My question is that what if the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for which $P(x)$ fails is *not* Lebesgue measurable? Then can we say whether $P(x)$ is true almost everywhere or not?

Comment: Well, if you follow the definition to the letter, a non-measurable set does not have measure $0$ (indeed, does not have a measure), and so the answer to your question is no, if $P$ fails for a non-measurable set, it does not hold almost everywhere.

Comment: The property holds almost everywhere if the set of $x$ for which it fails has Lebesgue measure zero. A non-measurable set does not have Lebesgue measure zero. In other words, the definition means just what it says.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @bof: this should be an answer.